# How to export kubeconfig file from existing cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Is there an easy way to export kubeconfig file from existing cluster so i can use it in CI/CD ?

Comment: Could you share more information? You want to get kubeconfig from `Google Kubernetes Engine` and run it on another `GKE` cluster or you want to take this config to another cloud providedr or local? Are you using any GKE specific features? Is it possible to give some scenario you want to achieve?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What kind of cluster is it? A managed(AKS,EKS or GKE etc) one, where is it deployed? Can you ssh in to master node, if yes, please

`cat /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` or `cat ~/.kube/config`

and copy the file, which is the **kubeconfig** for your cluster.

Other ways to create the kubeconfig, Run the following command

`kubectl config view --minify`, it will display all the info except for the client ca certificate and client key. The location of those keys depends on how the cluster is setup. `kubectl config view --raw` will show all the configuration (including certificates).

Answer (score 11):

First, locate your kubeconfig file. Generally, it is present at following location: `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

And then export it by running following command:

`export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

It is also a good idea to add it in `~/.bashrc` file so that you don't have to export it again when the kubeconfig changes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) to generate a kubeconfig entry, given that you have at least clusterViewer IAM role:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name
```

For reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#generate_kubeconfig_entry

Comment: that's to connect to the cluster within GCP, i want to get kubeconfig file from master so i can use it in 3rd parties website.

Comment: The link above is to generate a kubeconfig entry to access a cluster on GKE. You used the google-kubernetes-engine tag so I assumed your cluster is on GKE. Note that the link is to the GKE documentation.

Comment: that's true but i have to use service account with if i want to use it from 3rd party website.
i am working with Azure DevOps and i have to use `KubeConfig` as Authentication method. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Yep no worries, hope you get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have several clusters running on GKE and ssh'ing into the master node didn't work for me, but I was able to run `cat ~/.kube/config` locally and it gave me everything I needed including the certificate information I needed for my 3rd party application.

Make sure you connect locally so your kubectl is configured correctly,

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials`

Hopefully, that helps.